# these functions are analytic, then why integration is zero?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analytic-functions, cauchy-integral-formula

for both integrals below, consider c to be ccw unit circle.
I used Cauchy integral formula and I calculated the integral below:
$$\int \frac{{e^z}^2}{z^2} dz = 0$$ 
I used unit circle parametrization and I calculated the integral below:
$$\int Re(z).\bar{z} dz = 0$$ 
But does the results of integrals being zero mean, functions inside integrals are analytic on and in c? ( bc, Cauchy Goursat says integration would yield a zero if function inside integral is analytic every where in and on c) . They are not analytic I believe, so why are the integrals become zero?

Comment: $A \implies B$ does not imply that $B \implies A$. In other words, Cauchy-Goursat says that for analytic functions, the contour integral along closed curves is always equal to $0$. But nothing prevents non-analytic functions from also having zero contour integrals. In fact, the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) relates the value of the contour integral to the residues enclosed by the contour. The residues of functions $z^{k}$ at $0$ are all zero except when $k = -1$.

Answer (score -1):

if f is continuous on G (G is simply connected)and the integral of f = 0
then f is analytic on G.

(converse of Cauchy theorem is true if f is continuous)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).